# Zip File md5 Checksum - Every Time Different

Tags: java, android, md5, message-digest, md5-file

I have an Android applications which gets zip file's md5 checksum. I use it to compare the file with file on a server. My problem is that every time I try to generate the md5 for the same file, the checksum is different. I'm posting my methods here. Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
private static String fileMD5(String filePath) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int numRead = 0;
            while (numRead != -1) {
                numRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if (numRead > 0)
                    digest.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
            byte [] md5Bytes = digest.digest();
            return convertHashToString(md5Bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "ERROR";
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String convertHashToString(byte[] md5Bytes) {
        String returnVal = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < md5Bytes.length; i++) {
            returnVal += Integer.toString(( md5Bytes[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code to explain why you are getting different results.  The most likely explanation is that your data are different from run to run.  Even if you are pointing that method at the same file name, you will get different results if the file content is modified in any way between runs.

Comment: Your code does look okay... I would recommend first checking to see if you are always reading the same number of bytes from the file.

Comment: I printed the bytes number and every time it's the same..

Answer (score 0):

i try to solve same issue. I don't know how to solve it but I know reason :).

Reason is that zip file contains at least timestamp information about files. And this is what change you md5sum. Every zip entry is the same but this metadata information change result for md5.

Probably you already find answer somewhere else.

Comment: The ZIP format has no notion of time zone, so timestamps are only meaningful if it is known what time zone they were created in.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Answer (score 0):

As @michal-Šiplák mentioned

> Reason is that zip file contains at least timestamp information about
> files. And this is what changes your md5sum. Every zip entry is the same
> but this metadata information change result for md5.

To have consistent md5 you need to remove this variable and have it fixed as a constant. Bellow example

```
fun pack(sourceDir: File, zipFile: File) {
    ZipOutputStream(zipFile.outputStream()).use { zs ->
        val sourcePath = sourceDir.toPath()
        Files.walk(sourcePath)
            .filter { path -> path.isDirectory().not() }
            .forEach { path ->
                zs.putNextEntry(createZipEntry(path, sourcePath))
                Files.copy(path, zs)
                zs.closeEntry()
            }
    }
} 

fun createZipEntry(filePath: Path, sourcePath: Path): ZipEntry {
    val zipEntry = ZipEntry(sourcePath.relativize(filePath).toString())
    zipEntry.time = 0
    return zipEntry
}
```

key Line here is `zipEntry.time = 0` which makes metadata zip file constant.